# I don't want to be repetitive. How can I replace 'I teach English' or 'I give lessons in English'?

Tags: phrase-requests

I've tried to find some more expressions in dictionaries but with little success...

How many examples can you mention to express this activity? Do you know any informal expressions which can be used?

Comment: Why do you have to repeat this idea, in any case? Generally you'd tell someone when you first meet or write it in some sort of introduction - assuming you're not introducing yourself to the same person multiple times, saying "I teach English" to everyone you meet isn't repetitive (from their perspective).

Comment: Do you want to say that teaching English is your profession? If yes, then to say _I give English lessons_ would be a strange way to do so. _I'm an English teacher_ is much more likely.

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing the syntax. For example:

- As an English teacher...
- While teaching English...
- Teaching English is something.../enables me to...
- Like many English teachers, I...